# Java: stopping all activities in a thread from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I got two threads: `A` and `B`.

There is an endless loop in thread `A`:

```
while ( true ) {
    // Do something
}
```

Thread `B` is monitoring some state of interest to me. When the state changes, I want thread `A` to stop any further execution.

The following solution is not sufficient (setting `keepRunning` to `true` with method in `A` which is called from `B`):

```
while ( keepRunning) {
    // Do something
}
```

I can't wait for the body of the loop to be executed before thread `A` is halted - I want the execution of the methods called in the loop to be interrupted.

Is there a way to achieve the above functionality?

Comment: What exactly is happening in `//Do Something?` If you tell us this, we can give more specific advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a few point fixes, like checking `keepRunning` at key points in `A`'s loop. You could also interrupt thread `A`, which only helps you if it calls any methods that throw `InterruptedException`.

But you can't just have thread A stop dead in its tracks, and for good reason: this would be prone to deadlock. There used to be a methods [`Thread.stop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop--) and [`Thread.suspend`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend--) that did just that, and [they've been deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) because of those dangers. Starting in Java 8, that method [throws `UnsupportedOperationException`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html).

Basically, a thread has to stop itself. It can do so at the request of other threads (communicated by a field like `keepRunning` or by an interrupt), but it has to do it. One thread can't directly stop another.

Comment: Either one, actually.

Comment: I chose your "check at key points" suggestion and it turned to be not that bad - I had only about 6 of them. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can interrupt the Thread at any point, however this only triggers an InterruptedException in the method should check this.

You can attempt to stop a thread however, this is an unsafe operation as it can occur at any point and unless you are very careful, this can leave memory in an inconsistent state. If you are going to be that careful, you may as well add some checks and stop the code early.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really bad idea, because what happens when there are critical resources open, like e.g. a file? It won't be closed:

```
while (keepRunning) {
    openFile();
    // gets stopped here
    closeFile();
}
```

This can of course happen with other things as well, OS processes, network sockets, anything. You see why this is a bad idea?

You should instead redesign the code in the loop to check for the condition more often and break and cleanup if the condition doesn't hold true anymore.

```
while (keepRunning) {
    openFile();
    doLongOperation();
    if (!keepRunning) {
        closeFile();
        break; // or return
    }
    doAnotherLongOperation();
    closeFile();
}
```

This way, you don't lose the safety, while being able to stop it faster.

You might not actually use precious resources, but in any case you should tell us more details so we can give a more precise answer.